# How to allow user to install apk file one once on android phone?

Tags: android

Hi i have develop an android application in which i want to prevent user to create multiple account on our ftp server from one android device for which i create configuraton file and store boolean value which is by defult one but when user create account its value change to true. but there is an issue when user uninstall the apk file our configuration file also delete and user can create account again and boolean value lost.

My queston is that in android there is any registry like concept (same in windows) that we store value in android registry and when it try install it 2nd time it not allow it. or any another way which it more simple. any help in this regard is greatly apprecialted thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the device ID when the FTP account is created and storing the information on your server. That way if they try to create it again you can do a lookup, find that an account exists and return that back to the device. This way you know there is no chance of duplicates.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
tm.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: You might want to do some reading on the situation with android device ID's... it's not as straightforward as you'd think.

Comment: There are a few different ways to get a deviceId. Correct me if I'm wrong but that one should never change though there is a possibility that it wont exist (I'm yet to find an example of this). For that possibility I use the wifi mac address as a backup: WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();